# How to delete a doc from a subcollection using multiple filters in FlutterFlow?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using FlutterFlow and my firestore structure is like:

```
users
 contacts
 contact_history
 events
```

All are subcollections of "users". My rules are setup such that only users can see/edit/del their data.

I'm trying to delete a specific document from the "contact_history" subcollection, given a set of field values "eventUID" and "contactUID" but the query seems to come up empty and it never deletes  the doc.

I'm writing to the console to check values and the params are being passed properly but myLen and iter stay at zero. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to reference the "users" collection somehow?

```
Future actDelEventContactHist(
  String? myEventUID,
  String? myContactUID,
) async {
  int iter = 0;
  int myLen = 0;
  print('Begin: actDelEventContactHist -------');
  print('myEventUID: $myEventUID');
  print('myContactUID: $myContactUID');

  WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('contact_history')
      .where('contactUID', isEqualTo: myContactUID)
      .where('eventUID', isEqualTo: myEventUID)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) {
    myLen = querySnapshot.docs.length;
    print('myLen: $myLen');
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
      iter++;
      batch.delete(document.reference);
    });
    return batch.commit();
  });

  print('iter: $iter');
  print('Docs deleted');
  print('END: actDelEventContactHist  -------');
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. I had to include the 'users' collection as it's the parent. To do so I had to import the firebase_auth package. Solution below...

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future actDelEventContactHist(
  String? myEventUID,
  String? myContactUID,
) async {
  // Add your function code here!

  int iter = 0;
  int myLen = 0;
  print('Begin: actDelEventContactHist -------');
  print('myEventUID: $myEventUID');
  print('myContactUID: $myContactUID');

  final myId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(myId)
      .collection('contact_history')
      .where('contactUID', isEqualTo: myContactUID)
      .where('eventUID', isEqualTo: myEventUID)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) {
    myLen = querySnapshot.docs.length;
    print('myLen: $myLen');
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
      iter++;
      batch.delete(document.reference);
    });
    return batch.commit();
  });

  print('iter: $iter');
  print('Docs deleted');
  print('END: actDelEventContactHist  -------');
}
```